# How to "direct" sample from a 2D Gaussian distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, linear, eigenvalues

I checked the source code of `MASS::mvrnorm` function. Key parts are listed here

```
    function (n = 1, mu, Sigma, tol = 1e-06, empirical = FALSE, EISPACK = FALSE) 
    {
        ...
        eS <- eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE)
        ev <- eS$values
   X <- matrix(rnorm(p * n), n) 
   X <- drop(mu) + eS$vectors %*% diag(sqrt(pmax(ev, 0)), p) %*% t(X)
        ...
        t(X)
    }
```

It can be summarized into two steps:

- First generate two independent Gaussian distributions
- Second perform linear transformation (which is a matrix multiplication)  based on the eigen-vector of to co-variance matrix.

My question is is there any "direct" method of sample of 2D Gaussian instead of generate independent ones and transform it?

Comment: To help clarify your definition of "direct" - would generating a sample from a Gaussian(1,2) distribution be considered "indirect" if the method was to generate a standard Gaussian variate, multiply by 2, and add 1?

Comment: @jbowman thanks for your comment, I think myself is not clear on what is direct. that is why I put quote on. I just wonder is there any other method than linear transformation on independent Gaussians.

Comment: I suppose you could linearly transform dependent multivariate Gaussians :-).  But apart from that, wouldn't *any* other method necessarily be "indirect" in the sense of requiring some kind of transformation?  And among all possible transformations, which ones do you suppose are conceptually the simplest and easiest (and fastest) to compute?